# Searching for maximum path of zeroes in matrix

Tags: arrays, performance, list, python-3.x, matrix

Given an 10 x N matrix of 1's and 0s, such as:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

notes:

- the zeroes in a **column** are always between two runs of consecutive 1s. for example, a **column** such as `1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1` is not permitted
- there must be at least a gap of one zero in each **column**, ie a **column** such as: `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1` is not allowed

I want to find the longest consecutive streak of zeroes from left to right. In this case, that would be 4, which corresponds to the path starting in the second column of the 5th row from the top,

The second longest is 3 and there are 3 examples of that.

I'm a bit stumped on this, especially for very large N (~10M). I am looking for suggestions for the right approach/data structure to use or a similar problem and the algorithm used there. Another potential way to model the problem is to represent the problem using two lists:

```
L1 = [2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 3]
L2 = [6, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

but still not quite sure how to come up with an efficient solution

Comment: how large is N?

Comment: Since you have a maximum of 10 zeros and only `1` and `0` in the array, you could make strings of all rows and check if `'0000000000' in row` for all rows. If not, you continue with 9 zeros, and so on. Might not be great for 10M rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution using [***itertools.groupby()***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), `sum()` and `max()` functions:

```
import itertools

m = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]

max_zero_len = max(sum(1 for z in g if z == 0) 
                   for l in m for k,g in itertools.groupby(l))

print(max_zero_len)
```

The output:

```
4
```

---

`for l in m for k,g in itertools.groupby(l)` - will generate a separate group for each consecutive sequences of `1` and `0` values for each nested list. (like `[1,1], [0], [1,1], [0,0] ...`)

`sum(1 for z in g if z == 0)` - considers only `0`'s sequences and counts its length using `sum` function

`max(...)` - gets the maximum length among zero(`0`) sequences

Comment: give some adequate arguments for downvoting, if you not a coward

Comment: I didn't downvote, could you explain what's going on in the code a bit more?

Comment: @dimebucker91, see my explanation

Comment: I'm just trying to create some test cases with a bigger N value, how do you think this will work for such large inputs ?

Comment: try to make a test. As an alternative, we may consider using `numpy` module

Comment: doesn't seem to be able to handle 10 M inputs, maxes out at 1M, what would speed it up with `numpy` ?

Comment: no, it works I mean, but I need it to be faster for input of 10M, could you give me a suggestion for how to speed it up since it seems to do the job for slower cases

Comment: I think it is faster to focus on the vectors L1 and L2, I'm trying to build an approach based on that