# longest time lazy flappy bird can survive - consecutive gap between 2 arrays

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

given two arrays:

```
import numpy as np
L1 = np.array([3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1])
L2 = np.array([4, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7])
```

I want to efficiently find the longest consecutive gap that exists.

For example, let `i` be the ith index of both arrays.

```
    i = 0:  elements = (3,4) -> gap in range 3-4 -> longest path = 1
    i = 1: elements = (1,8)  -> 3-4 intersect 1-8 is 3-4 -> longest path = 2
    i = 2: elements = (4, 9) -> 3-4 intersect 4-9 is NULL -> longest path = 2

    ##this is what slows my approach down
    #now, we must return to i = 1

    i = 1: elements = (1,8) -> candidate interval is 1-8 -> path = 1, longest path = 2
    i = 2: elements = (4,9) -> 1-8 intersect 4-9 is 4-8 -> path = 2, longest path = 2
    i = 3: element = (2,5) -> 4-8 intersect 2-5 is 4-5 -> path = 3, longest path = 3
    ...
```

If you try to visualize it, it's a bit like that [flappy bird](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Flappy%20Bird&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_zJHQlJbTAhWMJ5QKHUqrBhkQ_AUIBigB&biw=1830&bih=1236&dpr=0.75#tbm=isch&q=flappy%20bird%20background) game, and so what I'm trying to find is the longest time the bird can remain at the same level without dying

I want a way to not track back, so that I only go through each `i` one time. Any suggestions? preferably in python

**update**

I wrote some code to visualise the problem (note I assumed here that the maximum number of rows is 10, this isn't always the case:

```
def get_flappy_matrix(ceiling, floor):
    '''
    given ceiling and floor heights
    returns matrix of 1s and 0s
    representing the tunnel
    '''
    ceil_heights = np.array(ceiling)
    floor_heights = np.array(floor)
    nmb_cols = len(ceil_heights)
    flappy_m = np.ones(shape=(10, nmb_cols), dtype=np.int)

    for col in range(nmb_cols):
        for row in range(ceil_heights[col], floor_heights[col]):
            flappy_m[row, col] = 0

    return flappy_m

N = 6
L1 = np.array([3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1])
L2 = np.array([4, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7])


m = get_flappy_matrix(L1, L2)

plt.pcolor(m, cmap=plt.cm.OrRd)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 10, 1), range(0, 11))
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, N+1),range(0,N+1))
plt.title(str(max_zero_len))
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

Now, from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43292162/4294028), this is one (still slow for large input) approach to the problem:

```
max_zero_len = max(sum(1 for z in g if z == 0) for l in m for k, g in itertools.groupby(l))
print(max_zero_len)
 # 5
```

Comment: You're going to have to explain some more. What do you mean by "straight line gap" or "consecutive gap"? Are you trying to find, say, the most walls you can shoot a horizontal shot through, with the two arrays representing lower and upper edges of holes in a series of walls? Or are you doing something completely different? You're making us guess a lot here.

Comment: Ah, good, you gave us more detail.

Comment: @user2357112 yeah sorry, i knew it was analogous to a game but i couldn't remember the name haha

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get your question. Can you explain more or can you give your final desired output with your two arrays ? It would be very helpful.

Comment: @ChihebNexus does that last edit help ?

Comment: Ok, so is this assuming that you are starting at a given position? What would the correct output be for the terrain given in your latest edit?

Comment: @gyre no, from the first example, the algorithm starts from the left, it keeps going and hits a block in the 3rd column (longest length 2), then it goes back to the second column and starts again, this time it keeps going for a max length of 5.

Comment: @gyre sorry, just realised i had mislabeled the y axis in the image, fixed now to correspond exactly to the algorithm I wrote out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a *window* of consecutive holes the bird can fly through. Extend it at the right one hole at a time, and remove holes from the left when necessary using the following strategy. When you reach the end, the longest window you managed to construct is the solution.

Track the lowest upper wall in the window, and the lowest upper wall that comes after that wall, and the lowest upper wall that comes after that wall, up to the last upper wall in the window. Do something similar for lower walls. For example, if the window goes from holes 3 to 9 here:

```
    | | | | | | | | upper wall sections
    | | | | | | |
    |   |   |   |
    |   |   |
    |   |   |
... | ------------- window
    | -------------
    |   |
      | | | |     |
    | | | | |   | | lower wall sections
    2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    wall numbers
```

then the upper bound walls are 6, 8, and 9, and the lower bound walls are 4 and 9. (We break ties by picking walls to the right.)

Say we extend the window to the tenth hole, and the tenth hole looks like this:

```
    | | | | | | | | |upper wall sections
    | | | | | | |   |
    |   |   |   |   |
    |   |   |       |
    |   |   |
... | --------------- window
    | ---------------
    |   |
      | | | |     |
    | | | | |   | | | lower wall sections
    2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    wall numbers
```

Upper wall 10 is lower than upper walls 9 and 8, so 9 and 8 are no longer upper bounds. The upper bounds are now 6 and 10, and the lower bounds are now 4, 9, and 10.

On the other hand, if hole 10 looked like this:

```
    | | | | | | | | | upper wall sections
    | | | | | | |
    |   |   |   |
    |   |   |
    |   |   |       |
... |               |
    |               |
    |   |           |
      | | | |     | |
    | | | | |   | | |
    2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    wall numbers
```

Lower wall 10 is higher than the lowest upper bound, so we need to remove walls from the left of the window. We advance the window to start at hole 7, removing everything up to the old lowest upper bound (wall 6), and we find that the next upper bound, wall 8, is high enough to produce a valid window:

```
    | | | | | | | | | upper wall sections
    | | | | | | |
    |   |   |   |
    |   |   | ------- window
    |   |   |       |
... |               |
    |               |
    |   |           |
      | | | |     | |
    | | | | |   | | |
    2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    wall numbers
```

If upper wall 8 had still been too low, we would have advanced the window to start at hole 9, and so on.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by lowest upper wall? why are the upper bound walls 6, 8, 9 and not 4,6,8?

Comment: @dimebucker91: 4 is tied with 6, so 6 wins because it's to the right. 9 is the lowest wall that comes after 8, so it's an upper bound. These are the walls that need to be removed from the window to give the bird room to fly higher.

Comment: We break ties this way because removing everything up to wall 4 doesn't let the bird fly any higher, since wall 6 is still in the way.

Comment: so in your example, we have the lists (starting from 2nd col):
`L1 = [2, 5, 2, 5,   2, 3, 1], 
L2 = [8, 7, 8, 8, 10, 9, 8]`
I'm still quite confused with the approach, i'll try to write some logic around the lists

Comment: when you say keep track of the holes, what is it that you are tracking? a list of tuples?

Comment: @dimebucker91: I was thinking of tracking them by index, since you need to know which ones they are, not just the L1 and L2 values.

Comment: how do you define a window? starting from the left, you don't really know where the window ends? doesn't this still involve tracking back each time

Comment: A window is any sequence of consecutive holes the bird can fly through without altitude adjustment. You won't know whether the current window extends as far right as it could until you hit a wall that requires removing walls from the left side of the window.

Comment: Both edges of the window only move right in the algorithm. No backtracking is necessary.

Comment: hmm.. i'm just not quite getting it.. so starting from the first elements in L1 and L2. we have (2,8). the lowest upper is 2 and the highest lower is 5. moving on to the second element, the lowest upper is now 5, the highest lower is now 7, moving on to the next, highest lower and lowest upper do not change, moving on to the next, still dont change, keep moving untill the lowest upper and highest lower range is zero?